# Abstract Algebra II

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)=\{a_1+a_2\sqrt{2}:a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$ Define on $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ the binary options $\oplus$ and $\odot$ as follows, given $a=a_1+a_2\sqrt{2}$ and $b=b_1+b_2\sqrt{2}$ for $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{Q}$:
>
> - $a\oplus b=(a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)\sqrt{2}$
> - $a\odot b=(a_1b_1+2a_2b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)\sqrt{2}.$
>
>   1. Show that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ is a ring under these operations.
>   2. Show that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ is a field under these operations.

I know all properties of ring and field but to compute the operation based on the binary operation defined on the $\oplus$ and $\odot$ is troublesome for me. Please someone should.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've taken the liberty of formatting your question with MathJax. Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, it appears that English may not be your first language. If so, I suggest that you add the [translation-request] tag when you edit your question to show your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$. Show that the given  operations coincide with the ones in $\mathbb R$. This will give that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a ring almost for free.

Answer (score 0):

*Another Hint:*

To show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is a field, you must show that every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse.

Note that $\left(a_1+a_2\sqrt2\right)\left(\dfrac {a_1} {a_1^2-2a_2^2} - \dfrac {a_2} {a_1^2-2a_2^2}\sqrt2\right)=1.$

Comment: multiplied by conjugate to get in base field